# Android: ways to achieve this Custom Checkable / Button

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

As you can see, there's the unchecked logo with a white circle on top right, then the checked version with a yellow border and an inner yellow circle in top right

What can I look into in order to get this behavior, maybe a project with a similar approach would help

[image: Logos of social networks]

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Can you show us the bug if you are getting any ?

Comment: I just got the unchecked state of the view without the the white circle on top right, I could put a checkbox on top of the image, but better have a custom view for the whole button so I can reuse it with different backgrounds

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

**XML code**

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="110dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                    android:id="@+id/cardMainFacebook"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
                    app:cardMaxElevation="1dp"
                    app:cardElevation="1dp"
                    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
                    app:strokeWidth="2dp"
                    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="100dp"
                            android:layout_height="100dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_facebook"
                            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">
                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/checkBoxMainFacebook"
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:button="@drawable/ic_check_box_button"
                    android:checked="false"/>
            </LinearLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"/>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="110dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                    android:id="@+id/cardMainFacebook1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
                    app:cardMaxElevation="1dp"
                    app:cardElevation="1dp"
                    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
                    app:strokeWidth="2dp"
                    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="100dp"
                            android:layout_height="100dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_facebook"
                            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">
                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/checkBoxMainFacebook1"
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:button="@drawable/ic_check_box_button"
                    android:checked="false"/>
            </LinearLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

**ic_check_box_button.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_focused="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/ic_radio_button_on" />
  <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_focused="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/ic_radio_button_off" />
  <item android:state_checked="false"
      android:drawable="@drawable/ic_radio_button_off" />
  <item android:state_checked="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/ic_radio_button_on" />
  <!--ic_radio_button_on is drawable for selected check box
  ic_radio_button_off is drawable for unselected check box-->
</selector>
```

**Java code** - ***Click on radio button and handle stroke of view***

Add `setOnCheckedChangeListener` Check box

```
checkBoxMainFacebook.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
checkBoxMainFacebook1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
```

Override `onCheckedChanged` method

```
  @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
        if(compoundButton == checkBoxMainFacebook){
            if(b){
                /*set stroke if checked*/
                cardMainFacebook.setStrokeColor(Color.YELLOW);
            }else{
                /*remove stroke if not checked*/
                cardMainFacebook.setStrokeColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            }
        }
        if(compoundButton == checkBoxMainFacebook1){
            if(b){
                /*set stroke if checked*/
                cardMainFacebook1.setStrokeColor(Color.YELLOW);
            }else{
                /*remove stroke if not checked*/
                cardMainFacebook1.setStrokeColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            }
        }
    }
```

***You can change color and icons according to your designs***

Output for above code is :

[image]